# Events update via AJAX and JSON when move into days or months or weeks

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I recently started to use Full Calendar and it's amazing must say but I have some doubts and isn't clear at docs. I have a method to get some events from my DB and this method return a JSON well formed string. I wish to use that method to build calendar events but with one particularity: if I'm in month view then days with event will be painted in blue and when I click on one day with events then I should go to this day view and then there shows all the events in that day.

How can I do this?
Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/V1tOr/cJPkP/1/

for jumping to day view:

```
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {


    calendar.fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay')
            .fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);

},
```

painting was a little tricky... I edited the soucecode (l: 2292, l: 2318)

```
beforeEventRender: function (view) {

    //clears day bgs
    $(".blue").removeClass("blue");

},
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {

     //warning!!! performance issue!!

    var _start = event.start;

    $('#calendar td[data-date="' + (_start.getFullYear() + '' + _start.getMonth() + '' + _start.getDate()) + '"]').addClass('blue');


}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: hi @v1tor it works perfectly thanks a lot now I must ask where is suppose that I render the events come from a JSON and generated by PHP code from a database? Any example in how to do this? I check the examples from the page but thisn't show any much, thanks again

Comment: thats the "easy" part. have a look at [link](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/). all you need is to return a valid json string.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try tomorrow at office and let you know if works or not!

Comment: Nice @v1tor it works. I need to more things but I was looking at Documentation in Event Rendering and also Agenda Options but none help me or at least this is what I think. So I need to hide events by default in month view and paint in blue for example those days where events are presented. For a better understanding go here http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ and see Wednesday, 1 has a event then in my case I need to hide that event but paint Wednesday, 1 background as blue. The method for painting is at Event Rendering docs but how to hide the events and how to determine where events are?

Comment: the other thing I need is to hide hours from day view because I don't use them all my events happen the entire day or more than one so it's ugly and get people confused if them see hours there. Any help on those two? Cheers and thanks for all your time

Comment: check - http://jsfiddle.net/V1tOr/cJPkP/6/ .regarding the second feature, I suggest using "basicDay" view

Comment: You rocks man, amazing this is what I want. Many thanks. I have a one question remaining. I call a PHP function via events that returns events from year, month, day for present day isn't a problem because I get the events for that day but if I move forward or backward how I pass the parameters year,month,day to my function? I notice start and end at AJAX call but in a format I can't understand. So what's your suggestion here? Also I have another post and will like if you can help me with that other too

Comment: for some reason my events days isn't get the blue class and that cause no color is painted there. Could you take a look what I'm doing wrong? The URL is http://comvivem.treswd.com/net user: demo, pass: demo and there go to "Eventos" and try to add a new one and see what I'm talking about

Comment: tks! start and end are passed as UNIX timestamps (seconds since 1970). use this to have a more readable format - date("c", $_GET["start"]). check -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for other formats. i'm unable to login... did you include the edited fullcalendar source? do you have the "blue" class in you css?

Comment: Hi the start is the previous date (Y,m,d) and the end is the next one but what about the default date? Maybe my logic is wrong but I need to know the actual date and also the previous, next dates how? Could you please write me a email to reynierpm at gmail dot com to give you admin credentials to this site? I'm trying to fix demo user but it not works so I leave there also I added the code as you suggested but it didn't works because the places with events doesn't painted and this is wrong.